# RESTSharp GET Call with Cookies

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp, rest

Using RESTSharp, I am able to login:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(Constants.APIURL + "method/login");
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        client.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddJsonBody(new
        {
            usr = username,
            pwd = password
        });

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(response.Headers.ToList().Find(x => x.Name == "Set-Cookie").Value.ToString());
```

I am then storing the cookies and sending to another API call, also through RESTSharp.

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(Constants.APIURL);
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("resource/Asset", Method.GET);
        request.AddCookie("Cookie", HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(cookie));
```

But it keeps returning 403 forbidden. I tried on POSTMan, it works absolutely fine.

Any help? Is it that I am sending the cookies wrongly? I tried sending the cookies in a `HttpWebRequest` and it is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Are you sure that `Cookie` is the correct name for the cookie? Maybe the server is expecting the cookie to be called something like `authorization`

Comment: I copied the RESTSharp generated code from POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried copy pasting a code generated from Postman where cookie was passed in a header but it didn't work. I tried sending cookie as below and it worked

`client.AddDefaultHeader("Cookie", cookie);`

Answer (score 0):

235 / 5.000
Resultados de traducción
For RestSharp v107 and >
You can use CookieContainer and in it store all received Cookies.
then pass the CookieContainer to RestClientOptions and use it as a parameter when instantiating var client1 = new RestClient(options);

CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
cookieJar.Add(response.Cookies);

```
        var options1 = new RestClientOptions(UL.moodle_host + "login/index.php?")
        {
            ThrowOnAnyError = true,
            UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0",
            FollowRedirects = true,
            CookieContainer = cookieJar
        };   



        // new request TRY loging
        var client1 = new RestClient(options1);
```